# how can I use angular js with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript

i wanna use angular js with bootstrap, so plz suggest me how..?

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
    <div class="row">

        First Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
    </div>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
    <br>
    <br> Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    });
</script>
```

its not working.

Comment: You need to include the source, and then inject the module.  There is an angular specific version of bootstrap btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use bower for front-end dependency manager. Open shell -> gitbash. Type `npm install -g bower`. HINT! Bower require npm, so if You dont have npm install it first! Go to project path, then run `bower install bootstrap`. After this You will notice new folder in project path. This solution is best on, becouse always get lastest release, all depencencies and sweet folder structure. I strongly recommend to use bower. Take a look at some gitbash repos, and notice most of plugins have bower installation guide. Link deps, like in index.html or some other view file, with is common for all of views. Remember to put in bottom, of body, to dont freeze page render.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-Sk3nkD6mLTMOF0EOpNtsIry+s1CsaqQC1rVLTAy+0yc= sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

To your index.html in the `<head>` section

Comment: hey thanks for your response but can you please tell me why you use integrity in tag?

Answer (score 0):

Add in your tag `<head>`, Bootstrap need jQuery, and you need to add Angular API

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```